# Distance between td to top of table (inside scrollable div)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I calculate the distance between the clicked `TD` element and the top of the `table`? The `offset` will not work in this case becase the table is inside a scrollable `div`.

I know that I could try to count the number of previous `TR` rows, and for each one get its height (since they can be different). But I am trying to look for a more direct and possible faster solution. Is there any other way that I am forgetting?

You can find a source code example in here.

https://jsfiddle.net/esa38vhv/

```js
$("#targetTable").on("click", "td", function() {
  alert($( this ).offset().top);

});
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #000000;">
  <table id="targetTable">
    <tr><td>a1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a3<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>16a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a17</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: *"You can find a source code example in here"* The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the table's offset, which is a minus value that you can subtract from the `td` element, and have the result as the TD offset from the top of the table.

Add this line;

```
alert($( this ).offset().top - $('table').offset().top);
```

---

Working demo:

```js
$("#targetTable").on("click", "td", function() {
  alert($( this ).offset().top - $('table').offset().top);
  
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #000000;">
  <table id="targetTable">
    <tr><td>a1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a3<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>16a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a17</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

Note that the border sizes are calculated as distances, which causes the first element to have an offset of 3 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, and use the `position()` method.

```js
$("#targetTable").on("click", "td", function() {
  console.log($(this).position().top);
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #000000;">
  <table id="targetTable">
    <tr><td>a1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a3<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>aa<br>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>16a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a17</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is still relative to the top of the window, not the offset of the top of the table

Comment: Are you sure? The [docs](https://api.jquery.com/position/) say: `The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent`.

Comment: If you click after scrolling down, you can see the height is not growing

Comment: Strange, it did for me, maxing our at 494.